# Inverse square law - brightness and distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, intensity

I am working on a lab report wherein I am given a bunch of readouts from an experiment that measures the brightness (lux) of light at set distances (cm).  When I apply the inverse square law,
$$\frac{I_1}{I_2}=\frac{d_2^2}{d_1^2},$$
the answer comes out way off of the expected distance.

Example: 
$$\sqrt{\frac{163.1\text{ lux}·(35\text{ cm})^2}{23\text{ lux}}}=93.20\text{ cm}$$
I would be expecting 10!  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Where do these numbers come from?

Comment: What are those numbers? which are lux, which are distances, and what are your units? Without further information it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: They are from the recorded data i have been given

Comment: Edited units sorry

Comment: The unit lux has a weighting factor associated with the response of the human eye called _illuminance_.  I am not sure that matters too much here.  Which illuminance do you know is correct?  Solve for the other one assuming the second distance is 10 cm.

Answer (score 3):

As $I_2 > I_1$ if $d_1 > d_2$, I think you just got your lux'es upside-down (inversed). What you wanted was $$35\sqrt{\frac{23}{163.1}}=13.14 $$ Is that close enough to $10$ for you?

Comment: Thats not what the inverse square formula says though.  I1/I2=D1^2/D2^2 where I1=163.1 I2=23 d1=35 and D2=10